# How could I display visual feedback when looping through items in a database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I'm making an item picking system in which the user will click a button and it will retrieve an item from a database to be picked. Once picked, the user will click the button and it will go to the next item in the table. I wanted to show a sort of visual display or feedback as the user clicks through each time.

Say there is 10 items that need to be picked I would have either a progress bar that increments each time until completion or even like a text indicator such as 1//10, 2/10, etc.

For reference I'll include my relevant code

Here is the js

```
<script >
var offset = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#button1').click(function(e) {
    $("#div1").empty();
    // pass offset value with GET request
    $.getJSON("getItem.php?offset=" + offset, function(result) {

    offset++; // increment the value after sucessful AJAX call
    $.each(result, function(i, field) {
        $("#div1").empty();
        $("#div1").append(JSON.stringify(result)); //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
});
});
}); 
</script>
```

and my php

```
mysqli_select_db($con,"orders");
$rows = null;
// Get the offset value
$offset = empty($_GET['offset']) ? 0 : $_GET['offset'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM orders Limit $offset, 1 "; // pass the offset value to LIMIT query

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
$rows[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);

echo json_encode($rows);
```

I've done some google searching but couldn't find any examples relevant to my idea, if someone knows how or could point to a solution of a problem similar to mine that would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what it is you are after, but if you want a simple loading animation you could probably do this with a combo of CSS, JS and Html.
Create div, and give it a class name or an ID. e.g loading
css for loading will look something like:

```
.loading{
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(255,255,255); /*What ever color you want*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

I'm not sure what you want to display while loading the next result, so for inspiration, have a look on codePen for loading animations. E.g https://codepen.io/Manoz/pen/pydxK

In CSS, create a class called displayNone.
The css will look like

```
.displayNone{
  display:none;
}
```

And then use JS to add/remove displayNone to the loading class depending on if you have results or not. You could even just create a @keyframes animation. Lot of ways.
https://spangle.com.au

Comment: thank you ill take a look. essentially say I have a table with 10 items, I'm trying to have something that says "item 1/10, 2/10," as they click through each item until 10/10 has been reached

Comment: All good :) I have seen some software that does what you are wanting to do, except was using a QR code scanner for the picking slips. It would flash the screen when a scan was done (I would use a keyframe animation for this and only play it once) and If I recall displayed 1 of 10 on the bottom of the page. May be a good design for you. I created a basic flash example on codepen for you which you can find at https://codepen.io/mitchell-boland/pen/NogpaG